# Python: Tween functions pyautogui.ease behave equals to pyautogui.linear()

Tags: python, tween, pyautogui

I'm trying to make an automated smooth mouse movement using pyauthogui. For that, I am using the tween functions like `easeOutQuad()`, `easeOutElastic()`, `easeInCubic()`, etc.
The problem is that the mouse is moving the same way as the default function `pyauthogui.linear()`.

I have tested this in conjunction with the Microsoft Paint app and the airbrush tool to see if it works or not. So my question is, am I missing something?

Using:
python 3.5
pyautogui 0.9.41

```
import pyautogui
import time

# Needed time to set focus to Paint app
time.sleep(2.5)

pyautogui.dragRel(800, 0, 2)
pyautogui.moveRel(xOffset=-800, yOffset=20, duration=0)

pyautogui.easeOutQuad(1)
pyautogui.dragRel(800, 0, 2)
pyautogui.moveRel(xOffset=-800, yOffset=20, duration=0)

pyautogui.easeOutElastic(1)
pyautogui.dragRel(800, 0, 2)
pyautogui.moveRel(xOffset=-800, yOffset=20, duration=0)

pyautogui.easeInCubic(1)
pyautogui.dragRel(800, 0, 2)
pyautogui.moveRel(xOffset=-800, yOffset=20, duration=0)
```

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOb7N.png)

Comment: You aren't actually using any of the tweening functions, you're just asking them to calculate a single point on their curve, and completely ignoring the results.  The way they're used is `pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100, 2, pyautogui.easeInQuad)` for example.

Comment: Ohh. You are right. That work very well. thanks for the quick response!